How to generate gaussian pulse train in LTspice
How can LTspice generate gaussian pulse train? Is there a way to use equations for that or it has to be done PWL way? Could not find an example in internet. Anybody has idea or experience with it?

Don't know, I'll let someone else answer it if possible, but if your pulse train is pre-baked anyway, you can generate to a csv file and have a voltage source pointed to said file. Is that an option to you?

Please provide an exact example of what you want to achieve. This MATLAB site has some suggestions that you may mean. But there are many many different meanings to your phrase that I've encountered in the last 50 yrs. And I do NOT want to be guessing about which of my experiences you reference. By the way, the integral of Poisson events makes up a Guassian curve. Other related ideas compound my confusion. So be as precise as possible. Too many meanings in my head, right now.

Let us consider the following Gaussian_: exp[-(wt)²], it is a solution of the first order differential equation: y'=-2w²y with initial conditions y(0)=1. This equation is simple to implement with one or two operational amplifiers in differentiator or integrator configuration, all driven by a positive unipolar square wave of adequate frequency depending on the Gaussian parameter.

Like others have mentioned, please post a drawing/plot of what you want these pulses to look like.
